# Can you create too many instances with Ktor

Tags: ktor, kotlin-multiplatform

Coming from `OkHttp` if you created too many instances of the OkHttp client you would you would eventually get `OutOfMemoryException` from having too many clients created.

Is this also something that you would have to worry about when using Ktor?

I am trying to migrate from okhttp to ktor to support `KMM` and have only a little experience with Ktor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create as many `HttpClient` as you want, like you could do with `OkHttp`.

It's up to you to make it **singleton** so that to have only one client instance.

You can do it by yourself or use a **DI library**.